# Scala: decompose the filter parameter on a Spark DataSet?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code and I need to type `x._1.` and `x._2.` a lot of times.

```
case class T (Field1: String, Field2: Int, ....)
val j: DataSet[(T, T)] = ...

j.filter(x => x._1.Field1 == x._2.Field1 
  && x._1.Field2 == x._2.Field2
  && ....)
```

Is it a way to decompose `x` to `(l, r)` so the expression can be a little bit shorter?

The following doesn't work on Spark's DataSet. why? How can Spark's DataSet not support Scala's language construct?

```
filter{ case (l,r) => ...
```

In F#, you can write something like

```
j.filter((l, r) -> ....)
```

even

```
j.filtere(({Field1 = l1; Field2 = l2; ....}, {Field1 = r1; Field2 = r2; ....}) -> ....)
```

Comment: `filter{ case (l,r) => ...`

Comment: I got the error of `Cannot resolve symbol filter` when trying `j.filter { case (l: T, r: T) => ... }

Comment: It got the error of `Error:(43, 14) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
    j.filter {` when compiled. The above error is returned by IntelliJ/Scala IDE.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the fact that `PartialFunction[A,B]` is a subclass of `Function1[A,B]`, so, you can use partial function syntax everywhere, a `Function1` is expected (`filter`, `map`, `flatMap` etc.):

```
 j.filter {
    case (l,r) if (l.Field1 == lr.Field1 && l.Field2 == r.Field2 => true
    case _ => false
 }
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, unfortunately this does not work with spark's `Dataset`. This seems to be due to the fact, that `filter` is overloaded in `Dataset`, and that throws the typer off (method overloads are generally discouraged in scala and don't work very well with its other features).

One work around for this, is to define a method with a different name, that you can tack on `Dataset` with an implicit conversion, and then use that method instead of `filter`:

```
object PimpedDataset {
  implicit class It[T](val ds: Dataset[T]) extends AnyVal {
   def filtered(f: T => Boolean) = ds.filter(f)
  }
}

...

import PimpedDataset._

j.filtered {
  case (l,r) if (l.Field1 == r.Field1 && l.Field2 == r.Field2 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

This will compile ...

Comment: It got the error of `Error:(43, 14) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
    j.filter {`

Comment: Hm, yeah ... Looks like there is something weird about spark's `DataSet` definition. I am not sure, why it's doing this. This works fine usually with all standard lib functions (or any custom-defined functions I have come across).

Comment: Spark's DataSet can mess up Scala's type system? It sounds very strange.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't mess up the type system. There is just something with the way it is defined that prevents the types to be inferred properly. If you spell the whole thing out, it'll work, albeit look extremely ugly:
`j.filter(new PartialFunction[(T,T), Boolean] { def apply(x: (T,T)) = x match { case (l,r) => ... } ; def isDefinedAt(x: (T,T) = true }})`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 it seems to be because of overloading. See my update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Spark's `Dataset` class has multiple overloaded `filter(...)` methods, and the compiler isn't able to infer which one to use. You can explicitly specify the function type, but it's a bit ugly.

```
j.filter({
    case (l, r) => true
}: ((Field1, Field2)) => Boolean)
```

That syntax (without explicitly specifying the type) is still available for `RDD`s. Unfortunately, in the interest of supporting Python/R/Etc, the Spark developers decided to forsake users preferring to write idiomatic Scala. :(